# Moving Requested Objects to Separate Rows within a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search filter that I would like to use to find channels on my page as the user is typing it. However, when calling on this API, I am unable to separate each object into a different row because the channel objects are all stored within the same row of the table data. I am storing the objects in their respective table data, but don't know a specific way of tackling this problem. Should I be using a for loop or perhaps add more table datas in my HTML? You can check out my codepen and remove the comment braces to run the last for loop within my function to get an idea.
https://codepen.io/baquino1994/pen/EvLrPV
HTML:

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
  <div class='container-fluid'>

  </div>
    <div class='text-center' id="border">
      <h1 id="font">Twitch TV JSON API</h1>
      <h2 id="fcc" target="_blank"></h2>
    </div>

<!--     <div class='spacer'></div>

    <div id="border">
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-3' id='channel'>
          Channel:<br>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3' id='status'>
          Status:<br>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3' id='game'>
          Game:<br>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3' id="logo">
          Logo:
      </div> -->
     <!--  <div id='follower'>Remove me<div> -->
<!--     </div> -->

      <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Channel.." title="Type in a name">
  <table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:25%;color:#FAF0E6">Channel</th>
    <th style="width:25%;color:#FAF0E6">Status</th>
    <th style="width:25%;color:#FAF0E6">Game</th>

    </tr>
  <tr>

    <td id="channel"style="color:red"></td>
    <td id="status"></td>
    <td id="game"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
    </div>
        <div class='spacer'></div>

<!--   </div> -->
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background-image:url('https://www.twitch.tv/p/assets/uploads/combologo_474x356.png');
}
#border {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 35%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    } 
  a{
  color:white;
}
.spacer {
    padding: 1%;
  }

/* * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
} */

 #myInput {
 background-position: 10px 10px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 12px;

}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color:black;

}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color:red;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#channel{
  color:red;
}
#font, #fcc, .header, #channel, #status, #game {
  font-family: 'Saira Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.intro{
  color:green;

}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
 var follower = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas", "brunofin"];
  //An array of users or in this case, streamers that will be placed on the document.
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp', 
    headers: {
      'client-ID': 'ziu3fledjh14rd812socrwluiz1o31'
    },
    // Twitch requires a client id to request their data now. You can bypass this by using the https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/ESL_SC2?callback=? url to request certain objects. However, some objects won't be available if you do choose to bypass registering for a client_id.
    success: function(data) {
     if (data.stream === null) {
        $('#fcc').html(' FreeCodeCamp is Offline');
      } else {
        $('#fcc').html(' FreeCodeCamp is Online!');
      }
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert("Error");
    }
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < follower.length; i++) {
//change this to get
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + follower[i], 
      headers: {
        'client-ID': '59x9ex7f5zzongzntqx0zrwleoxy12'
      },
      //You could also use $.getJSON and use the client_Id as a token to request Twitch's objects.
      success: function(dataI) {
        var name = dataI._links.self.slice(37)
        if (dataI.stream === null) {
          $('#status').append(' is Offline<br>')
          $('#channel').append('<a target="blank" href="https://www.twitch.tv/' + name + '">' + name + '</a><br>')
          $('#game').append('N/A<br>');
        } else {
          $('#status').append(' is Online<br>')
          $('#channel').append('<a target="blank" href="https://www.twitch.tv/' + name + '">' + name + '</a><br>')
          $('#game').append(dataI.stream.game + '<br>');
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert("Error: One or more users is no longer avaialble");
      }
    });
 }

//  for(var i=0; i< follower.length;i++){
//    $.ajax({
//      type:'GET',
//      url:'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'+ follower[i],
//      headers:{
//       'client-ID': '59x9ex7f5zzongzntqx0zrwleoxy12'
//    },
//      success: function(d2){
//        var logo = d2.logo;
//        if(d2.logo == null){
//       $('#logo').append('<img src= http://jesusldn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/noimage.png>')       
//      }
//      else{
//      $("#logo").append('<img src='+logo+">'")
//    }

//      }

//    });






//  }








})
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

I have a provided a link to my codepen, as it has the Jquery plug-in and Bootstrap.

Comment: where is codepen link?

Comment: I just added it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

your filter works like a charm. Issues is with table creation.

you need to update your code to add `<tr>` dynamically to table.

remove tr from html:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Channel.." title="Type in a name">
  <table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:25%;color:#FAF0E6">Channel</th>
    <th style="width:25%;color:#FAF0E6">Status</th>
    <th style="width:25%;color:#FAF0E6">Game</th>

    </tr>

</table>
    </div>
        <div class='spacer'></div>
```

change your success method to this:

```
success: function(dataI) {
        var name = dataI._links.self.slice(37)
        console.log(follower);
        if (dataI.stream === null) {
          $('#myTable').append('<tr>'+
            '<td><a target="blank" href="https://www.twitch.tv/'+name + '">' + name +
            '<td>is Offline</td>'+
             '</a></td>'+
            '<td>NA</td>');

        } else {
          $('#myTable').append('<tr>'+
            '<td><a target="blank" href="https://www.twitch.tv/'+name + '">' + name +
            '<td>is online</td>'+
             '</a><'+
            '<td>NA</td>');

        }
      },
```